# NServiceBus ServiceInsight - Empty Flow Diagram and Sequence Diagram

Tags: nservicebus, serviceinsight

- I started ServiceControl (Set audit forwarding on)
- I Started ServiceInsight (with default api url, which is ok)
- I Downloaded StepByStep sample from nservicebus site, and added audit forwarding config class

.

```
class ConfigAuditQueue : IProvideConfiguration<AuditConfig>
{
    public AuditConfig GetConfiguration()
    {
        return new AuditConfig
        {
            QueueName = "audit"
        };
    }
}
```

As you can see in the screenshot, it is connected to msmq api and can fetch the messages. However Flow Diagram and Sequence Diagrams are empty.

1. Why is that, any ideas?
2. Is it related to the **Unknown** *Message ID* ? (Although it is known in Header)

[image: SS]

Here is also MSMQ installed features screenshot and versions for helping error recreation.

- ServiceControl v1.12.0
- ServiceInsight v1.5.6

[image]

Comment: Yes the lack of message id is the issue, but it seems odd, can you try and contact support at particular.net? I'll try to reproduce this on my machine...

Comment: I tested this locally and it work ok for me...

Comment: And believe me I'm getting same error on 2 different laptops.. I added some more info for error recreation. And sure I can contact to support also. I hope you can recreate the same environment with these extra info. Looking forward to hear again, thanks.

Comment: Upgraded ServiceControl to v1.13.0, still not working..

Comment: When you select a message in the "Messages" window to load the diagram data, it will issue a HTTP request which will get logged. Could you find that and execute manually to see if it returns any data? In the logs search for something like http://yourservicecontrol:port/conversations/someguid and see what data it returns when executed in your browser or any rest client you may have.

Comment: Yes, I can also manually get data by using api directly from browser (http://localhost:33333/api/messages/525daa77-d774-4017-8897-a5e9010c4a8c/body) ServiceInsight logs this like this:
https://justpaste.it/tayp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending some time trying to track the issue, turns out this is a ServiceControl bug that happens when running on non-English culture, specially Turkish.

The bug has been raised and fixed since. You can find more info [here](https://github.com/Particular/ServiceControl/issues/717).

Comment: Thanks for all your efforts. It works now with ServiceControl 1.14

Answer (score 0):

This issue is crossposted to the Particular Google Groups:

- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/particularsoftware/B1ShuXJzCnE/avGGyZMdBQAJ

This seems to be any a bug and an issue is created for it:

- https://github.com/Particular/ServiceInsight/issues/576

Comment: Thank you for the github issue. Please let me know if you need further infos (log files etc)